# OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied using uinput

Tags: python, input, raspberry-pi

I am using the `os` module on my raspberry pi to reboot it when a certain button is pushed which, is connected to the raspberry pi's GPIO. However, when I run the below code, I get an error message.

[image]

I have tried changing permissions on the python file and I already ran the `modprobe` input as well. If anyone could help me that would be amazing!

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import uinput
import os

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

GPIO.setup(19, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.setup(20, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)

time.sleep(1)
device = uinput.Device([uinput.KEY_F5])

view = 'm'

while True:
    input_state_back = GPIO.input(19)   
    input_state_forward = GPIO.input(20)

    if input_state_back == False:
        print('Button F5 Pressed')
        device.emit_click(uinput.KEY_F5)
        time.sleep(0.5)
    if input_state_forward == False:
        print('Button Reboot Pressed')
        os.system('sudo reboot')
        time.sleep(0.5)
```

Comment: Did u try first load it with `modprobe uinput` in terminal before running your script?

Comment: Please copy the code when you're asking on SO, rather than posting screenshots (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: @IronFist I have ran sudo mod probe input before trying to run my python code but, I get the same results

Comment: @KyrheePowell .. it's not `sudo mod probe input` but instead `sudo modprobe uinput` ! And may be you should try it without the `sudo` as `modprobe uinput` only

Comment: @IronFist Sorry my computer auto corrected(Mac problems) and I did not notice but, yeah that's what I ran. sudo modprobe input!

Comment: `uinput` and not `input` right?

Comment: @IronFist yes... I got to start proofreading. Sorry, I am really tired right now!

Answer (score 0):

try to execute your program from bash with `sudo python nameProgram.py`
i had the same error, but doing this i could run my program. it will not work in the normal python window, but i couldn't find other ways to make this work

Answer (score 0):

One of possible decision is launch environment under root. When you use idle, you can:

```
sudo idle
```

Now, when you launch the file, your problem must be excluded.